# How to create a custom form using CRUD controller in sonata admin bundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm a beginner in sonata admin, I need to know how to create custom form using route and controller and index.html.twig.

```
   app.admin.category:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: adminn, label: Category }
        public: true
```

Comment: Try to look here: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html

Comment: Bandele? Sorry, please read Sonata's documentation and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create CRUD controller. For each admin service you have default one and you can overwrite it. 
In your case, service is `app.admin.category`

How to create CRUD controller? I am going to explain the most simple way.

1. Create class in your `AppBundle/Controller/Admin/`folder and call it CategoryAdminController. 
   Here is code of your class:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

   use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

   /**
    * Class CategoryAdminController
    * @package AppBundle\Controller\Admin\
    */
   class CategoryAdminController extends CRUDController
   {
   }
   ```

   As you can see this class extends default SonataAdminCRUDController.
2. Then point to your sonata service that it has to use this class as it's CRUDContoller. 
   In your service.yml change the stndard CRUD controller:

   app.admin.category:
       class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
       arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, AppBundle:Admin\CategoryAdmin]
       tags:
           - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: adminn, label: Category }
       public: true
3. Now you are ready to make your new action in your new Controller. Let's call it changeAction.

   ```
    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function changeAction($id = null)
    {
        try {
           if ($id !== null) {
               $category = $this->admin->getObject($id);
           }
       } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
           error_log($e->getMessage());
       }

       // .. Here is a code of creating your custom form with variable $form


       return $this->render('@App/Admin/CRUD/index.html.twig', [
           'custom_form' => $form->createView(),
       ]);
    }
   ```
4. Make the route to your new action! In your `CategoryAdmin` service overwrite `configureRoutes()` method

   ```
   /**
    * @param RouteCollection $collection
    */
   protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
   {
       $collection->add('change', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/change');
   }
   ```
5. Finally - we can make the button to our route:

   ```
   /**
    * @param ListMapper $listMapper
    */
   protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
   {
       $listMapper
           //.. Your fields...
           ->add('_action', 'actions', [
               'label' => ' ',
               'actions' => [
                   //'show' => array(),    // I removed show action button, but you can uncomment
                   //'edit' => array(),    // I removed edit action button, but you can uncomment
                   //'delete' => array(),  // I removed delete action button, but you can uncomment
               'change' => [
                       'template' => 'AppBundle::Admin\CRUD\Buttons\change_category_button.html.twig',
                   ]
               ]
           ])
       ;
   }
   ```

And of course don't forget to create a twig template for your new button and place it in right place `AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin/CRUD/Buttons/`:

```
//'AppBundle::Admin\CRUD\Buttons\change_category_button.html.twig':

{% if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('change') %}
    <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('change', object) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary edit_link" title="Your title here"  style="display: inline-block">
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on"> </i>
        Change Button
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you for explaining me this line   return $this->render('@App/Admin/CRUD/index.html.twig', [
        'custom_form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
 }

Comment: @ahmedchega You should mark this answer as correct - then the rest of community won't try to answer this question. As it has been already answered!

Answer (score 0):

staskrak solution is not working for me any more for latest symfony/sonata. So I adopted solution from https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/cookbook/recipe_custom_view.html

Just add file admin/my_form.html.twig like

```
{# templates/admin/my_form.html.twig #}

{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block sonata_admin_content %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

and use it in SomeAdminController

```
public function batchActionMyAction(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery, Request $request = null)
{
    $this->admin->checkAccess('edit');
    $this->admin->checkAccess('delete');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder([])
        ->add('smsText', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Task'])
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('Admin/my_form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```